# Custom CommonDialog/PrintDialog Newbie Question

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to create my first custom Print Dialog in C#.  I found some samples online that I'm working with to do this.

What I want to do is to put a button underneath the Properties button in the upper right corner.  The code samples I have seen so far put new controls on the bottom of the Dialog relative to the position of the OK and Cancel buttons.  Those code samples allow one to retrieve the handle of the OK or Cancel buttons because they're universal constants in Dialog controls.  Fair enough, but how would I go about getting the handle on the Properties button so I could insert my button underneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SPY++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(VS.60).aspx) to figure out the control Id of any control, those ids a solid across Windows versions. You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996463.aspx) (old but still relevant) on how to use SPY++ to obtain control Ids.